# How can I install .apk file generated in Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, apk

application works during the debug. When I generate .apk file and move it into my mobile phone, an error "App not installed" appears in my Android after the installation.

What I did:

1. Change Solution Configuration to Release
2. Check compatible Android versions in the project properties
3. Clean and rebuild project in the project explorer
4. Archive Android project
5. Open file with .apk file and move this file into mobile phone with Android
6. Open .apk file, installation start
7. Then error "App not installed" occurs

Does anyone know, what may cause this problem?

Thank you for your response!

Comment: You title says that you cannot generate an APK but the description you tell that you have an APK but cannot install. Please update either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy the **released** version apk to mobile, you could refer to [the official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/)
.

At least, **the apk should be signed.**